# Angular mat-table - HTML element in a cell

Tags: angular, dynamic

I don't know if this is possible but mayB someone could help me ..

I have a MAT-TABLE (Angular material) with many columns (I built a MatTableDataSource and everything is dynamic)

In one of these columns I'd like to put an information i'm getting from an other application :

- if the information is not null, i just display it as a string in the column (no problem for this)
- if the information is null, I'd like to put a select element in my cell

So i'm doing the following in the TS file :

• if (information not null) => data = [...,attribut:information,...]

• if (information is null) => data  = [...,attribut:`<select><option>test</option></select>`
,...]

But it appears as a string in my application and not as an HTML element
How can I proceed ?

what i want to do, but easier explaination :

```
public test: any;
this.test = `<select><option>opt1</option><option>opt2</option></select>`;
```

in template :

```
<div>
  {{test}}
</div>
```

but here my result :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRCmr.png)

how to build an HTML element in my TS file and then show it in my html file ? thanks

Comment: share you code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component with this HTML markup and append that component dynamically into the container.

Visit https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader for more details.

Without creating it as a component, it won't be working as a select HTML markup.

Comment: Missing *Sanitization*

Comment: i got this result : opt1 opt2
but no select HTML element
should I type test different as "any" ?

Comment: @Helene Sorry, I thought the markup is static. Please view the updated solution.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean by "append that component dynamically into the container." ? What container?